# array of objects and creation of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an object (a bank) which has an array of clients and bankID.
My problem is that I don't know how to create a bank in main function.

Bank class:

```
public class Bank {
   Client[] client=new Client[20];
   String idBank;

   public Bank(Client[] client,String idBank) {
      this.client=client;
      this.idBank=idBank;
   }

   public Bank(Bank b) {
      b.client=client;
      b.idBank=idBank;
   }
```

Client class:

```
public class Client {
   String name;
   String address;
   BancAccount[] banc=new BancAccount[50];

   public Client(String name,String address,BancAccount[] banc) {
      this.name=name;
      this.address=address;
      this.banc=banc;
   }

   public Client(Client c) {
      c.address=address;
      c.name=name;
      c.banc=banc;
   }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Lab5 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Bank[] b1=new Bank(client[3],"14332");
   }
}
```

These is the problem :

You have to create a program to simulate a bank activity. The system includes the following modules: Bank — clients (array of Client)  — idBank (String) 
 5
BancAccount  — accountNumber (String)  — amount (float)  Client — name (String)  — address (String)  — accounts (array of BankAccount; a client can have at least an account, but not more than five accounts)

Comment: What is the 3 being sent to the bank constructor? I thought you said bank takes an array of clients?

Comment: I wrote that just to have an ideea of what should be there(the number of clients which is stored in an array), I don't know how to do that....

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what you were doing (sans the erroneous `[]`):

```
Bank b1 =new Bank(3,"14332"); //works, but BAD
```

Now, that's not very pretty, is it? Let's talk about your `Bank` class. Specifically, this part:

```
Client[] client=new Client[20];
public Bank(Client[] client,String idBank)
{
   this.client=client;
   this.idBank=idBank;
}
```

It doesn't make very much sense to pass `3` in as opposed to an array of `Client`s. It also seems strange that you declare the `Client` array like this:

```
Client[] client=new Client[20];
```

But you then force the array to be reassigned to something else when a `Bank` constructor is called. Let's add another constructor:

```
public Bank(int numClients,String idBank)
{
   client = new Client[numClients];
   this.idBank=idBank;
}
```

and perhaps an `addClient(Client c)` method that will enforce the max client size, and a variable to keep track of our current index in the array (essentially making this act like an `ArrayList`):

```
private int index = 0;
public void addClient(Client c) {
   if(index == client.length)
      return; //or throw an Exception, your choice here.
   client[index] = c;
   index++;
}
```

Now, if you want to keep all your classes the same, then you can also just do something like this in `main()`:

```
Client[] clients = new Client[20]; //or whatever number of Clients is appropriate
//Code to instantiate Clients, whatever that may be
Bank = new Bank(new Client[]{}, "14332");
```

Comment: Or you can simply use Collections - an ArrayList as an example - to get rid of tedious job of working with arrays. `List<Client> clients;` as a field and you can add to it by `clients.add(client);`

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari I would have done that to begin with, but OP is obviously just starting to learn the language, and this is probably a homework assignment. I am trying to avoid going into anything too complicated (such as Generics, Collections, etc...).